# How to make Matlab 2011b support Visual C++ express 2012 in a 64bit system?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, c++11

How to make Matlab 2011b to work with Visual C++ 2012? It seems

```
mex -setup
```

cannot locate visual C++ 2012 compiler.

Does that mean a better solution is only to use Visual C++ 2010 instead?

But I also want to use the C++11 new features.

What should I do?

Comment: Technically, this should be possible, but you won't receive any support from the MathWorks if things go wrong. You'll have to create a mexopts.bat, and may a couple other files for VS2012. Take a look at [this patch](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93013-how-can-i-use-microsoft-visual-c-2010-to-create-mex-files-with-matlab-7-10-r2010a) from MathWorks supports for enabling VS20120 on R2010a. You'll need to do the same thing for VS2012.

Comment: thank you very much! this is very interesting! I would prefer to have a Visual C++ 2010 express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011b/win64.html - the newest compiler that can be supported for R2011b is Visual C++ 2010.  This is probably why MATLAB can't find your compiler.  If you want to use Visual C++ 2012, you'll need to upgrade your version of MATLAB.

The earliest version of MATLAB that supports Visual C++ 2012 is R2013a - http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/index.html?sec=win64

As such, you'll either need to stick with Visual C++ 2010 for R2011b, or upgrade your version of MATLAB to R2013a that provides Visual C++ 2012 support.

This is probably not the information you wanted to hear.  Good luck anyhow!